# How to switch to beta channel on Android Studio Chipmunk?

Tags: android, android-studio

Followed the instructions as given here - https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview#change_your_update_channel

There is no dropdown to select the channel. Is there any other way?

[image: Cannot find dropdown to select beta channel]

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Answer (score 6):

You can install the Beta and other version using the [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/). In the Toolbox click three-dots menu -> Other Versions.

Comment: Is it really the only option? I don't really want to have multiple instances installed ... it seems that it worked somewhere in the past to change the given installation to target to a different channel. Why they canceled this feature?

Comment: It's a shame they killed this. I wouldn't mind if Dolphin was not so stupid. But I have 20gb of disk space left and this option would have really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer switch channels from within Android Studio as of Chipmunk or Dolphin, instead you need to install the correct preview installer(beta/canary) from https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Comment: Stupid google...always "fixing" things

Answer (score 0):

The option seems to be missing from `Dolphin` as well.

For installing **Android Studio** itself you can use the Toolbox App as suggested by @viachaslau-tysianchuk.

For installing **SDK components** from canary / dev / beta channels you can use the command line `sdkmanager` by specifying the `--channel` flag, like so:

`./cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --channel=1 "extras;google;auto"`

**Note** that the `cmdline-tools` are not installed by default, you should first install them via the old SDK tools or just download from here: https://developer.android.com/studio#cmdline-tools